# Mapping Unique 16-Digit numeric ID to Unique Alphanumeric ID

Tags: java, random, mapping, unique, hash-function

In a project I'm working on, I need to generate 16 character long unique IDs, consisting of 10 numbers plus 26 uppercase letters (only uppercase). They must be guaranteed to be universally unique, with zero chance of a repeat ever.

The IDs are not stored forever. An ID is thrown out of the database after a period of time and a new unique ID must be generated. The IDs can never repeat with the thrown out ones either.

So randomly generating 16 digits and checking against a list of previously generated IDs is not an option because there is no comprehensive list of previous IDs. Also, `UUID` will not work because the IDs must be 16 digits in length.

Right now I'm using 16-Digit Unique IDs, that are guaranteed to be universally unique every time they're generated (I'm using `timestamps` to generate them plus unique server ID). However, I need the IDs to be difficult to predict, and using `timestamps` makes them easy to predict.

So what I need to do is map the 16 digit numeric IDs that I have into the larger range of 10 digits + 26 letters without losing uniqueness. I need some sort of hashing function that maps from a smaller range to a larger range, guaranteeing a one-to-one mapping so that the unique IDs are guaranteed to stay unique after being mapped.

I have searched and so far have not found any hashing or mapping functions that are guaranteed to be collision-free, but one must exist if I'm mapping to a larger space. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Guaranteed to be universally unique when you don't store previous ones makes this problematic. Any idea about how many IDs you expect to generate over a lifetime?  For example, if you take the mac address and time stamp, and encrypt it with AES encryption, then base-64 encode it, and take every other letter or digit, that may work. But, it won't be guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Well the 16 digit timestamp + server ID is guaranteed to be universally unique at generation without checking it against a list, the problem is mapping it to a larger range to 'fuzzify' it without losing that uniqueness. Your suggestion with AES encryption would take away that uniqueness, so I can't use that.

Comment: How can you be so sure two 16-digit IDs won't be duplicates if they're generated by two threads on the same server at the same instant?

Comment: I'm using Javas atomic-reference class to ensure that.

Comment: That helps you only if everything happens in one JVM per server, and in that server the singleton holding the ID is loaded under a single classloader.  Sounds pretty brittle to me.  I think this might be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Are you sure you can't change things to use a UUID instead?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: This is an updated answer, as I misread the constraints on the final ID.**

Here is a possible solution.

Let set:

- UID16 = 16-digit unique ID
- LUID = 16-symbol UID (using digits+letters)
- SECRET = a secret string
- HASH = some hash of SECRET+UID16

Now, you can compute:

```
LUID = BASE36(UID16) + SUBSTR(BASE36(HASH), 0, 5)
```

BASE36(UID16) will produce a 11-character string (because 16 / log10(36) ~= 10.28)

It is guaranteed to be unique because the original UID16 is fully included in the final ID. If you happen to get a hash collision with two different UID16, you'll still have two distinct LUID.

Yet, it is difficult to predict because the 5 other symbols are based on a non-predictable hash.

NB: you'll only get log2(36^5) ~= 26 bits of entropy on the hash part, which may or may not be enough depending on your security requirements. The less predictable the original UID16, the better.

Comment: The LUID must be 16 characters as well. Can't be longer than that.

Answer (score 0):

You want to map from a space consisting of 10<sup>16</sup> distinct values to one with 36<sup>16</sup> values.

The ratio of the sizes of these two spaces is `~795,866,110`.

Use `BigDecimal` and multiply each input value by the ratio to distribute the input keys equally over the output space.  Then base-36 encode the resulting value.

Here's a sample of 16-digit values consisting of 11 digits "timestamp" and 5 digits server ID encoded using the above scheme.

```
Decimal ID          Base-36 Encoding
----------------    ----------------
4156333000101044 -> EYNSC8L1QJD7MJDK
4156333000201044 -> EYNSC8LTY4Y8Y7A0
4156333000301044 -> EYNSC8MM5QJA9V6G
4156333000401044 -> EYNSC8NEDC4BLJ2W
4156333000501044 -> EYNSC8O6KXPCX6ZC
4156333000601044 -> EYNSC8OYSJAE8UVS
4156333000701044 -> EYNSC8PR04VFKIS8
4156333000801044 -> EYNSC8QJ7QGGW6OO
```

The first 11 digits form the "timestamp" and I calculated the result for a series incremented by 1; the last five digits are an arbitrary "server ID", in this case `01044`.

Answer (score 0):

[Brandon Staggs](http://www.brandonstaggs.com/) wrote a good article on [Implementing a Partial Serial Number Verification System](http://Implementing%20a%20Partial%20Serial%20Number%20Verification%20System). The examples are written in Delphi, but could be converted to other languages.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12908105)

Comment: The second link is broken.  I think it is meant to go to [Implementing a Partial Serial Number Verification System](https://www.brandonstaggs.com/2007/07/26/implementing-a-partial-serial-number-verification-system-in-delphi/) but can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

One general solution to your problem is encryption.  Because encryption is reversible it is always a one-to-one mapping from plaintext to cyphertext.  If you encrypt the numbers [0, 1, 2, 3, ...] then you are guaranteed that the resulting cyphertexts are also unique, as long as you keep the same key, do not repeat a number or overflow the allowed size.  You just need to keep track of the next number to encrypt, incrementing as needed, and check that it never overflows.

The problem then reduces to the size (in bits) of the encryption and how to present it as text.  You say: "10 numbers plus 26 uppercase letters (only uppercase)."  That is similar to Base32 encoding, which uses the digits 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and 26 letters.  Not exactly what you require, but perhaps close enough and available off the shelf.  16 characters at 5 bits per Base32 character is 80 bits.  You could use an 80 bit block cipher and convert the output to Base32.  Either roll your own simple [Feistel cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) or use [Hasty Pudding cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_Pudding_cipher), which can be set for any block size.  Do not roll your own if there is a major security requirement here.  Your own Feistel cipher will give you uniqueness and obfuscation, not security.  Hasty Pudding gives security as well.

If you really do need all 10 digits and 26 letters, then you are looking at a number in base 36.  Work out the required bit size for 36^16 and proceed as before.  Convert the cyphertext bits to a number expressed in base 36.

If you write your own cipher then it appears that you do not need the decryption function, which will save a little work.